# Even light emmission from area light in Eevee?

Tags: light, eevee-render-engine

So I know that emmissions dont interact with volumetrics (fog in my case) in eevee if you don't bake in the lighting, but the emmission planes are going to be moving. I had the idea to use area lights as a stand in as I can animate them to move with the planes, but I can't seem to find a way to get the light to emmit across the area lights, they're just emmiting from the center like a spot light.

is there any way I can get the light to emmit equally across the surface of the area light? or am I gonna have to just put 700 lights down? I'd render it in cycles, but its a 90 seconds long animation at 60fps, and I don't think my Vega 64 and Ryzen 1600 will finish it before the heat death of the universe.[image]